# Maximum Validity period for Italian Visas

Tags: schengen, italy

I followed this https://hotels.ng/guides/visa/italy-visa-information-nigerians/ 
 and got very confused that I had to ask.

Please I need to know the Maximum validity Period for Italy Visas. Does Italy give Visas for upto 2 years like the US and Canada.

Answer (score 5):

Schengen visas (which are what Italy issues) **can** be issued with a validity of up to 5 years.

It is up to the issuing consulate how long a validity they **will** issue visas with. Visas with long validity are only supposed to be issued to travelers with a known travel history and a demontrated need to make *frequent and regular* visits to the Schengen Area. Different consulates interpret these guidelines differently.

The vast majority of first-time applicants will only get a visa that covers the particular period of the visit they document in their application, perhaps extended with a week or two at each end to allow for minor changes of plans.

Comment: It is not clear if the question is about a long term multiple-entry Schengen Visa.

Comment: @zaph: My assumption is that the OP is not particularly aware of such subtleties, so this answer lumps all kinds of short-stay visas into one. It is the same application anyway.